# \pgfplotstabletypeset inside wrapper macro

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am currently trying to write a wrapper for `\pgfplotstabletypeset` but I got stuck pretty soon.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\newcommand{\insertTable}[1]{
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
        every head row/.style={output empty row},
        every first row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        header = false,
        /pgfplots/table/assign cell content/.code={
            \IfDecimal{#1}{ 
                % format as number 
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\pgfutilensuremath{\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}}
            }{ 
                % use as String -> has to span two columns if col sep align is activated
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablepartno=0%
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1}
                \fi
            }
        },
        col sep = comma, 
        use comma,
    ]{#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{filecontents}{Sample.csv}
        Col 1, Col 2, Col 3, Col 4, Col 5, Col 6, Col 7
        1.34, 2.73, 358000, 0.003, 5, 1500, 0.000374
        1.34, 2.73, 358000, 0.003, 7, 1325.4, 0.012356
        1.34, 2.734, 358000, 0.003, 12, 998.331, 0.12345
        1.34, 5.073, 358000, 0.003, 17, 12353.274583, 0.0505134567
        1.34, 22.77, 358000, test, 356, 9999.99, 0.3
    \end{filecontents}

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
        every head row/.style={output empty row},
        every first row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        header = false,
        /pgfplots/table/assign cell content/.code={
            \IfDecimal{#1}{ 
                % format as number 
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\pgfutilensuremath{\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}}
            }{ 
                % use as String -> has to span two columns if col sep align is activated
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablepartno=0%
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1}
                \fi
            } 
        },
        col sep = comma, 
        use comma,
    ]{Sample.csv}

    \insertTable{Sample.csv}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I am defining `\insertTable` as my wrapper-macro. However I am experiencing a behaviour I can't really explain to myself:
When compiling above document I get two tables (as expected). The first one (generated by directly using `\pgfplotstabletypeset` contains the data just the way I want it to. The second one however has the exact same number of rows and columns but each cell is filled with the text `Sample.csv`.
As you can see in the above code the used call for `\pgfplotstabletypeset` is the same in both cases.

I was able to track the problem down to me assigning the cell content myself. if I remove the `/pgfplots/table/assign cell content/.code = {...}` block everything works as expected (I get the expected error as I am not explicitly using `string type`).

The current behavior indicates to me that the argument passed to the cell-content-assigning code is different in both cases. In case 1 this is the expected unformatted cell content and in case two it is the filename in each case.

Why is that so? And how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a common mistake. `#1` is used as the placeholder for the argument given to the macro you're defining. If you need to define a macro inside this macro (or access arguments which should be given to a macro) you have to escape the `#` with an additional one, so `#1` becomes `##1`.

You must use `##1` for the arguments which should be considered in `\pgfplotstabletypeset` and are not the argument to `\insertTable`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\newcommand{\insertTable}[1]{
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
        every head row/.style={output empty row},
        every first row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        header = false,
        /pgfplots/table/assign cell content/.code={
            \IfDecimal{##1}{ 
                % format as number 
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\pgfutilensuremath{\pgfmathprintnumber{##1}}}
            }{ 
                % use as String -> has to span two columns if col sep align is activated
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablepartno=0%
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{##1}
                \fi
            }
        },
        col sep = comma, 
        use comma,
    ]{#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{filecontents}{Sample.csv}
        Col 1, Col 2, Col 3, Col 4, Col 5, Col 6, Col 7
        1.34, 2.73, 358000, 0.003, 5, 1500, 0.000374
        1.34, 2.73, 358000, 0.003, 7, 1325.4, 0.012356
        1.34, 2.734, 358000, 0.003, 12, 998.331, 0.12345
        1.34, 5.073, 358000, 0.003, 17, 12353.274583, 0.0505134567
        1.34, 22.77, 358000, test, 356, 9999.99, 0.3
    \end{filecontents}

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
        every head row/.style={output empty row},
        every first row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        header = false,
        /pgfplots/table/assign cell content/.code={
            \IfDecimal{#1}{ 
                % format as number 
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\pgfutilensuremath{\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}}
            }{ 
                % use as String -> has to span two columns if col sep align is activated
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablepartno=0%
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1}
                \fi
            } 
        },
        col sep = comma, 
        use comma,
    ]{Sample.csv}

    \insertTable{Sample.csv}
\end{document}
```